# ARKit line between two SCNNode

Tags: arkit, arimageanchor

it is possible to draw a line from an SCNNode to another and keep the line 'updated' when the user move around the device? In my scenario I have to ARImageAnchor and I would like to create a line between this two points.

Answer (score 0):

I have a demo creating line between two node https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YDUq7nfvXBc&feature=youtu.be if this is what u want u can comment below

Comment: Yeah, I can adapt this for ARImageAnchor

Comment: @sanam shrestha Very interesting. Please provide a link to your repo/some code.