# How do I draw a line between two points using ARSKView (i.e. ARKit + SpriteKit)?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, arkit

I know that if I'm using ARSCNView (i.e. SceneKit), I can [draw a line using something like a cylinder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53828730/how-to-draw-dashed-line-in-arkit-scenekit-like-in-the-measure-app) since SceneKit has a 3D environment and drawing something between two 3d points is supported natively.

However, I'm trying to create an interface like Apple's measure app:

> [image]

The rendered elements (e.g. the line and the `3'3"`) don't look 3D, so I was thinking I should use ARSKView (i.e. SpriteKit) for this. Placing a single element such as the  emoji in Apple's ARKit + SpriteKit template is pretty trivial, since you simply need to implement the method:

```
func view(_ view: ARSKView, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor) -> SKNode? {
    return SKLabelNode(text: "")
}
```

This associates a 2D object (SKNode) with a 3D position (ARAnchor).

What I can't figure out how to do is how to draw a line between two nodes.

Is there any way to draw a line between two nodes like in the image above using SpriteKit, or must we switch over to SceneKit to achieve this effect?

---

Note: This is not a duplicate of the following questions since those questions talk about SceneKit (3D), not SpriteKit (2D):

- [Draw straight line from start value to end value ARKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45916390/draw-straight-line-from-start-value-to-end-value-arkit)
- [ARKit line between two SCNNode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54463858/arkit-line-between-two-scnnode)